# how to use php select to display entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I plan on doing is to list all my users from my table, display them in a list and then have the current entry in the table highlighted in the drop down list.

This is my current code:

```
print "<option value=".$row2['user_id']."     if($row2['user_id']==$row['user_id']){ echo     'selected=\"selected\"';}>".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."</option>";
```

but it does not work.

At the moment my current code which does work is like this:

```
<?
//$results4 = mysql_query("select * from user_info order by fname");

$data2 = "select * from user_info order by fname";

$result2 = mysql_query($data2);
print "<select name=\"timesheet_approver_1\">";
print "<option value=".$row['user_id']."             selected='selected'>".$row['fname']." ".$row['lname']."</option>";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
print "<option value=".$row2['user_id'].">".$row2['fname']."     ".$row2['lname']."</option>";
}
print "</select>";
?>
```

This lists all my entries but adds the one in the table listed at the top. Im just stuck as to how i can just list all entries and have the one in the table highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed if statements within print statements as you have attempted.

But, you can compare without the if using the ternary operator:

```
print "<option value='".$row2['user_id']."' " .     ($row2['user_id']==$row['user_id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' .     $row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']. "</option>";
```

Works like so:

```
echo ( $a == $b ? 'a==b evaluates true' : 'a==b evaluates false' );
```

From the manual

```
"The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE."
```